# SQL Server : Total value for all months in a year

Tags: sql-server

I have data for various months for example Jan,Feb,Mar and for various ID.

I want the total sum for each month and different IDs to be merged into one column.

I want the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS05Y.jpg) in this format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to do a lot of improve your post. Firstly: Provide sample data, and expected results in **text** format, don't by post images. Next explain your question, what is it you need help with? Finally, show what you've already tried; SO isn't a free coding service, it's a Q&A website.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the month. The IDs can be concatinated using [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT   STRING_AGG([DATA IDs], ','), [Month], SUM([Value])
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY [Month]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  Stuff((SELECT ',' + dataIds
              FROM   test_agg where month = t.month
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as "Data Ids", Month, sum(value) as Total from test_agg t group by month;
```

Comment: Also is there any function to split the output 2279,2280, this is the version I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   A

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.